# MVC HTML Action Link Post ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I have a list of skills which I wish to display endorsers for , to achieve this I decided to post the ID using an HTML Action Link and then retrieve the endorsers within another DIV Class:

The div class which displays all the skills as hyperlinks:

```
 <div class="skill">
 @foreach (var skl in model.userskills)
 {
 @Html.ActionLink(@skl.userskill_content , "Index" , "Home" , new  {skl.userskill_id} , null);
 </div>
```

The div class which displays all the endorsers:

```
<div class="endorsers">
@foreach (var skill in model.endorsers)
{
@skl.user_forename  @skil._user_surname
}
</div>
```

How do I pass the 'new {skl.userskill_id} ' into the controller so this can that each endorser based on this specific userskill_id? So if I click on this hyperlink "C#' skill , it will load a list of endorsers based on the ID of 'C#'.

I hope this is clear as it can be . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `id=` before the parameter:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@skl.userskill_content ,   
 "Index" , "Home" , new  {id = skl.userskill_id} , null);
```

You must also make sure that the controller action is an HTTP get as an `ActionLink` will invoke this, and also make sure your controller parameter matches i.e

```
public ActionResult AnAction(int id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Parametername= before the parameter. like action parameter name **Id** than

```
  @Html.ActionLink(@skl.userskill_content ,   
         "Index" , "Home" , new  {id = skl.userskill_id} , null);
```

OR

```
  @Html.ActionLink(@skl.userskill_content ,   
         "Index" , "Home" , new  {parameterName= skl.userskill_id} , null);
```

pass same name parameter. you have define in controller action.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)!